# Fixing mac/windows new lines with git pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-bash

In our office we working in a team of about 10 developers. Most of them have a Mac machines. Recently I've realise when I'm checking differences of my work (after changing only one line of code) almost each line is changed, but `git diff` shows you change is exactly same as original. After some research it's turned out to be a different new line. Before I do anything it's '\r\n' (CR+LF, 0x0D0A) and after my change all non Unix new lines (\r\n) are change to Unix one (\n).

I realize I could ask my colleagues to change their IDE settings, but I realize I can just prepare some script that need to be run each time they make a commit.

How can I run a bash script before git commit? How can use git pre-commit hook?

Answer (score 7):

Everything is explain on https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings
and here http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking-out_and_checking-in

For Linux/Mac machines use

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

For Windows machines use

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

with this settings git will convert all `\r\n` line endings to `\n` before every commit.

Comment: Macs now use `\n` as line ending. I cannot find the source, but this is fact.

Comment: That's true http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations BUT seems some of my colleagues IDE is set to non-Unix line ending.

Comment: Windows users _may_ want `\n` line endings too. In that case it's better to handle the conversion in a git hook.