# I need a git command to convert file line ending in Macintosh (CR) to Windows (CRLF) in windows

Tags: windows, git, newline, line-endings, core.autocrlf

git config --global core.autocrlf true command is not helping.

Also if there is a python script which can change the line endings for multiple files together, it will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all CR to CRLF in text file using CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912941/convert-all-cr-to-crlf-in-text-file-using-cmd)

Comment: Actually it doesn't because it requires me to download docs2unix which is not authorised to install. For this I would either need a python code or a git command

Comment: Are you looking for LF endings (modern macOS) or CR endings (ancient MacOS 9 and before)?  Git will handle the former just fine, but not the latter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing mac/windows new lines with git pre-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223290/fixing-mac-windows-new-lines-with-git-pre-commit-hook)

Comment: Is there a python code that will help with fixing the CR endings in windows. I read this issue occurs in the rarest of case. The DDL I pulled from Teradata has CR endings and it needs to be changed to either CRLF or LF endings.